# When should one implement own Hash Table instead of using objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, hashtable, javascript-objects

Are there any scenarios where we use custom Hash Tables instead of objects for storing and accessing Key-value pairs in JavaScript?

Comment: Maybe if you're asked to do so in an interview, but otherwise, I don't think re-inventing the wheel is productive. If you need extra functionality, you can usually define your own functions.

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.

Comment: Hmm, maybe a hash table where the order of keys is important for some reason. Or OO where you have to add methods to some hash class. But in both of these examples, we'd rather use an Array or a Map these days. So it's rather uncommon imho that a custom hash table is preferrable.